# How to solve $y''(t) \cos t + y (t) \cos t=1$ in $\left (-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right )$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm solving a problem in ODE:

> Solve in $\left (-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right )$ the ODE $y''(t) \cos t + y (t) \cos t=1$

In my lecture, we are given three theorems:

> $\textbf{Theorem 1} \quad$ If $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two linearly independent solutions to $y''+ay'+by=c$. Then
>
> i) The system $$\begin{bmatrix}y_1 & y_2 \\ y_1' & y_2' \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}h \\ k \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ c \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ (in which the unknown functions are $h$ and $k$) has a unique solution.
>
> ii) All the solutions $s$ are of the form $t \mapsto H y_1 +K y_2$ where $H,K$ are anti-derivatives of $h$ and $k$.

and

> $\textbf{Theorem 2} \quad$ Homogeneous case
>
> If we can find a solution $y_1$ to $y''+ay'+by=0$, then we can determine another solution $y_2$ by using undetermined constant method to look for a solution of the form $y_2 = \lambda y_1$ in which $\lambda$ is a function.

and

> $\textbf{Theorem 3} \quad$ Superposition Principle
>
> Consider $y''+ay'+by= c_i \quad (E_i)$ in which $c_i$ are functions. If $y_i$ is the solution to $(E_i)$ then $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i y_i$ is the solution to $y''+ay'+by=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i c_i$.

---

I'm unable to apply those theorems to solve this ODE. Unfortunately, my professor's never solved an example with non-constant coefficients in class. The lectures are very likely to contain typos. I'm sorry for that because I'm unable to recognize them.

Could you please elaborate on how to solve this ODE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{equation} y''(t) \cos t + y (t) \cos t=1\\
\implies y''(t) + y (t)=\sec t\\
\implies (D^2+1)y=\sec t\tag1
\end{equation}
where $~D\equiv \dfrac{d}{dt}~$

Let $~y=e^{mt}~$ be solution of $$(D^2+1)y=0\tag2$$ Putting the value of $y$ in $(2)$ we have $$m^2+1=0\implies m=\pm ~i$$

So solution of equation $(2)$ is $$y=A\cos t +B\sin t$$where $~A,~B~$are constant of integration.

Here **Complementary function** of equation $(1)$ is $$y_c=A\cos t +B\sin t$$where $~A,~B~$are constant of integration.

Now for **particular integral** $y_p$,

let $~u=\cos t~$, $~v=\sin t~$

Here $$W=\begin{vmatrix}
u & v \\
u' & v'
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
\cos t & \sin t \\
-\sin t & \cos t
\end{vmatrix}=1\ne 0$$
Then $$y_p=uf(t)+vg(t)$$
where $$f(t)=-\int \dfrac{vR}{W}~dt=-\int \sin t\cdot \sec t~dt=\log(\cos t)$$
$$g(t)=\int \dfrac{uR}{W}~dt=-\int \cos t \cdot\sec t~dt=t$$
$R ~: ~$Non-homogeneous part of equation $(1)$$~~=\sec t~$.

Hence $$y_p=\cos t~\log(\cos t)+t~\sin t $$

Therefore the general solution of equation $(1)$ is $$y=y_c+y_p$$
$$\implies y= A\cos t +B\sin t+\cos t~\log(\cos t)+t~\sin t$$where $~A,~B~$are constant of integration to be determined by the given condition.

Comment: Hi, I would like to ask how do you get $f(t)=-\int \dfrac{vR}{W}~dt=$ and $g(t)=\int \dfrac{uR}{W}~dt$?

Comment: This is the "method of variation of parameters" for solving $$y''+Py'+Qy=R$$ type differential equation where $~P,~Q,~R~$are functions of $~x~$or constants

Comment: You choose $~u=\cos t~$ and $~v=\sin t~$ because $y_c=A\cos t +B\sin t$, right?

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it.

Comment: Yes, you are right (for your second last comment)@Abstract Analysis

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

$$y''Cosx+yCosx=1$$
$$y''Cosx-y'Sinx+y'Sinx+yCosx=1$$
$$(y'Cosx)'+(ySinx)'=1$$
$$y'Cosx+ySinx=x+c$$
$$y'+ytanx=(x+c)Secx$$
Now this is 1st order linear differentiable equation